# session_id() not getting session variables

Tags: php, session, hosting, session-variables

I have a homebrew CMS installed on two different web servers. Each maintain the same code. I have had a really annoying problem when I try passing `$_SESSION` variables between different domains.

My CMS is on domain1.com. The website it is controlling is on domain2.com. My system passes all the session variables for the login information from domain1.com to domain2.com via a url link (domain1.com has a link like this: `http://domain2.com?sessionId=1gh...`)(sessionId is generated by session_id()). domain2.com retrieves the session id and does `session_id($_GET['sessionId'])` to set the session and grab the variables. It then proceeds to show a bar at the top with admin features.

This system works well on one of my hosts, as well as my localhost. But I recently transferred to a different host and installed my CMS with the same code with success. Everything works except for this feature. When I click on the link and try to set the session_id, the session_id changes, but the `$_SESSION` variables are removed. When I return to my CMS, I have to relogin. Somehow on this host, changing the session_id deletes the `$_SESSION` variables.

I have never liked session variables and I would not use them if I were to start again (I would probably use plain cookies). But I really need to figure this out. The host that it works on is Bluehost, with both domains hosted by Bluehost. The host that it does not work on is [EDIT]ByteHost, and the domain registrar is Godaddy.

Here is some example code from domain2.com:

...

```
if ( $_GET['sessionId'] )
{
 session_id($_GET['sessionId']);
}

session_start();

echo session_id(); // returns the proper sessionId passed through the url

print_r($_SESSION); // does not work. returns array()

...
```

I can guarantee that the `$_SESSION` variables existed before, because I was still logged into my CMS.

Any ideas why session variables work on 1 host, but not on another?

I tried replacing the php.ini file with the working host one. Problem was still there.

Thank you for your time!

**UPDATE**

I ended up removing this from my CMS. Now, I just pass the login details over the url and it logs the person in. It works a lot cleaner.

Comment: So you are expecting the session information to load just by setting the session id?  This will only work if the two domains are on the same physical server....

Comment: They are both on the same physical server. The only difference is the domain registrar. Does the domain registrar have to do with it? Why has it always worked beforehand?

Comment: But can you verify the same apache/php daemon is running both sites?

Comment: phpinfo() shows both running 5.2.17

Comment: I'm sorry. I just figured out it is hosted by "bytehost", cpanel.net hosting reseller.

Comment: So its a different host? Clearly this machine does not know anything about the stored session variables on the other machine.

Comment: no, it is the same host for both domains. the difference is domain registrar

Comment: wonder if changing the `session save_handler` will have any effect ? are your `session.save_handler` values from `phpinfo` in all the hosts same ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some reasons why this may not be working:

- **different physical server**
- **different account for each domain** (even if it's the same physical server)
- **different apache/php daemon for the domains** (some shared hosting sites will create a separate directory for each domain, and then restrict apache from sharing information between domains.  This will also have the effect of preventing session information from being passed.  Think about it - do you want someone else's domain on the same hosting provider to have access to YOUR client's session info?)
- **configuration (apache or php), or .htaccess rules**

Here is what I will recommend: **stop doing this**.  This is a great opportunity to fix a very serious security flaw in your code.  By the time you diagnose it with the hosting provider, you could probably just rewrite everything you need using HTML5 storage or secure cookies.

My guess is that the hosting provider is smart enough to protect session information form being stolen from another domain.  But in either case, I *strongly* recommend you change the code so that it does not need to steal session information from another domain.

Comment: I guess a workaround would be to just pass the user's login details through the url and then relogin. I should try that

Comment: ... and then anyone who accesses that url will have access to the user's login details ......

Comment: it doesnt work. when i start a new session, it still logs out of the CMS

Comment: Like I said, you should probably just rewrite your code.  You are trying to make an insecure, non-standard methodology work.  You really need to just rewrite it without the sessions dependability.

Answer (score 0):

To have a session on multiple domains you would need to have the session id passed in the url instead of the sessions cookie as cookies only work on a single domain basis.

Using subdomains would solve the problem if they're not separate customers `a.domain.com and b.domain.com`

Comment: (a) if it's in a cookie, then you can use javascript to read it and send it to the second domain, and (b) he's already passing the session id in the url and it's not working

Comment: He IS passing the session ID in the URL when crossing domains.

Comment: Subdomains will not directly solve the problem, unless you configure the session cookies to be valid for a wildcard domain name.

Comment: Fair point - but where is he grabbing the session data from once the session_id has been set on domain2.com? Session data is stored in temp files and unless there is a session already generated, then there's nothing to grab on domain2.com.

Comment: It's a pretty horrid workaround, but he could pass a unique_hash/key across to domain2.com (not a session_id) and match against the user_id (presumably in a DB) and automatically create a session for the same user --OR-- create a "keep me logged-in" function for both sites...

Comment: @nickhar: because the domains are on the same physical server, he was able to steal the session info because apache/php was using the same temp files for *all* domains.  This was a security vulnerability in his prior hosting provider.  Now that he's switched hosts, who actually understand the security implications, he's trying to find a way to hack around it.

Comment: @cegfault and hence why I was trying to find simple yet not-too-horrific ways of achieving said hack without compromising security at a very fundamental level.

Comment: agreed, but any way you look at it, he needs to rewrite it to *not* use sessions